# Keyboard, wifi, graphics card and trackpad not working in Microsoft Surface Book 3

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, surface

I bought a Microsoft Surface Book 3 and tried to install Ubuntu, but the keyboard, wifi, graphics card and trackpad didn't work.

I tried to install the custom kernel for Surface but it didn't help.

How can I get this working? I need Ubuntu for college classes.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with a 3rd party kernel, you will get better feedback if you can identify the specific issue that relates to Ubuntu and rephrase the question focused on that issue.  For example, for the kernel you mention, the installation guide says that Surface Book 3 is supported and they have a Debian package available, but it also says you need to add modules to "initramfs/initrd".  If you didn't know how to add those modules, that might be a more relevant question for askubuntu, but if you tried and it still didn't work, you might reach out to the support channel for the 3rd party kernel.

Also, if you just need to get up and working for college, I would consider installing Ubuntu on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which will avoid all the compatibility issues, but still let you have a full (non-GUI) Ubuntu installation inside of Windows.  https://ubuntu.com/wsl